How can I automate the connection to an On Prem Windows VM that uses Azure AAD for authentication?
My requirement is to automate the transfer of files, and running commands on the Windows VM, which is currently a manual process where I log in to the VM via RDP (and it prompts me for my username/password of my account).
I have been doing a bit of digging on this, as I am able to automate the same thing for a Linux VM where no such AAD based authentication exists and I use the paramiko library to transfer content from my PC to the VM and run bash commands.
client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

# Connect to the server
try:
    client.connect(host, username=username, password=password)
    
    # Initialize the SFTP client
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    
    # Transfer the file
    sftp.put(local_file_path, remote_file_path)
    print(f"File {local_file_path} has been transferred to {remote_file_path} on the remote server.")
    _stdin, _stdout,_stderr = client.exec_command("ls random*")

(Omitted content for brevity and confidentiality)
However, getting a set of credentials to log in to the Windows VM isn't allowed as per the org policy.
I am not really able to find any online resources on the same, beyond this and this but in the latter, it seems all be related to a simpler scenario where there is a username/password combination. I am investigating the usage of Pywinauto to try this out, but I am still not really sure on what the best approach really is. Personally, I would prefer to use Python but I am amenable to any solution at this point (or at least being pointed in the right direction).

To automate the connection to an On Prem Windows VM that uses Azure AAD for authentication, you can use Azure Bastion. Azure Bastion provides secure connectivity to all of the VMs in the virtual network in which it's provisioned. Using Azure Bastion protects your virtual machines from exposing RDP/SSH ports to the outside world, while still providing secure access using RDP/SSH

I have done some digging @Rukmini. Since this is for a client who is running a private cloud, the closest thing I have found is Mutual Authentication using Kerberos. Do you have an idea on how that one works?
